# From QGIS to AutoCAD Civil 3D: object data of shapefile not found

Tags: qgis, shapefile, autocad, civil3d

My colleague and I have been trying to import a shapefile, that I made in QGIS, into AutoCAD Civil 3D. So far we have managed to get the correct geometry, but the object data/attributes don't show up in the import dialog of Civil 3D.

I found [this thread](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/civil-3d-forum/mapimport-object-data-no-coming-in/td-p/10308649/page/2) which seemed to be the same problem as we have, but we have tried this solution and it doesn't work. When my colleague mapimports the shapefile from that thread she gets all the object data, but if I import that shapefile into QGIS and export it and we try to mapimport that file again into Civil 3D, it doesn't work anymore. This leads me to believe the problem has to be related to QGIS.

We don't use dxf because the attribute table gets lost in the process and this is crucial information for the labelling in Civil 3D.

**[EDIT: Link to shapefile](https://we.tl/t-DiAbK5uIuc)**

The attribute table should contain 3 attributes: label, status and detail. There should be 2 features in CRS EPSG:31370.

What is wrong here?

Versions:
Autodesk Civil 3D 2022
QGIS 3.4.5-Madeira

Comment: Can you post a link to your data?

Comment: QGIS 3.22 can export DXF files also.  You can upgrade your version.

Comment: I used your data and workflow in QGIS 3.26.3-Buenos Aires and Civil 3D 2022. Object Data shows up OK. Did you click the "Create Object Data" button?